# No Visible @interface for 'MLVPieChartView' declares the selector 'tick'

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa, cocos2d-iphone

Still new to this iOS thing, running through a tutorial and I have this No Visible @interface error, which I saw other threads on but nothing that I could find an answer too, I looked through spelling an no answer.

```
**MLVViewController.m**
#import "MLVViewController.h"
#import "MLVPieChartView.h"
#import "MLVPieSlice.h"

@interface MLVViewController ()
{
    MLVPieChartView *pieChartView;
    NSTimer *timer;
}
@end

@implementation MLVViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    pieChartView = [[MLVPieChartView alloc] initWithFrame: self.view.frame];
    [self.view addSubview: pieChartView];


    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1/30.0 target:self selector:@selector(nextFrame) userInfo:NULL repeats:YES];

}

- (void) nextFrame
{
    [pieChartView tick];
    [pieChartView setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *t = [touches anyObject];
    [pieChartView touchedPoint: [t locationInView: pieChartView]];
}


@end




**MLVPieChartView.m**

#import "MLVPieChartView.h"
#import "MLVPieSlice.h" 

typedef enum
{
    STATE_IDLE,
    STATE_ROTATING,
    STATE_SEPARATING,
    STATE_SEPARATED,
    STATE_JOINING
}   state;


@implementation MLVPieChartView

{
    float xPos, yPos, radius;
    float rotationAngle;
    state animationState;
    BOOL isAnimating;
}

@synthesize pieChart;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        pieChart = [[MLVPieChart alloc] init];
        xPos = 320/2;
        yPos = 330;
        radius = 120;
        rotationAngle = 1;

        [self setState: STATE_IDLE];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) setState:(state) newState
{
    animationState = newState;
    switch (newState) {
        case STATE_IDLE:
            isAnimating = NO;
            break;
        case STATE_ROTATING:
            isAnimating = YES;
            break;
        case STATE_SEPARATING:
            isAnimating = YES;
            break;
        case STATE_SEPARATED:
            isAnimating = NO;
            break;
        case STATE_JOINING:
            isAnimating = YES;
            break;
    }
}

- (void) tick
{
    switch (animationState)
    {
        case STATE_ROTATING:

            break;
        case STATE_SEPARATING:

            break;
        case STATE_JOINING:

            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [self drawPieChart: context];
}


- (void) drawPieChart:(CGContextRef) context
{
    //clear the screen
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480));

    //draw all slices
    float a = rotationAngle;
    for (MLVPieSlice *slice in pieChart.slices) {
        [self drawPieSlice:slice withStartingAngle:a withContext:context];
        a += (slice.pct/100) * (M_PI * 2);
    }
}


- (void) drawPieSlice:(MLVPieSlice *) slice withStartingAngle:(float)startAngle withContext:(CGContextRef) context
{
    float endAngle = startAngle + (slice.pct / 100) * (M_PI * 2);
    float adjY = yPos;
    float rad = radius;

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [MLVPieChartView colorFromHexString: slice.color].CGColor);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0);

    CGContextBeginPath(context);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, xPos, adjY);
    CGContextAddArc(context, xPos, adjY, rad, startAngle, endAngle, 0);
    CGContextClosePath(context);

    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);
}

float easeInOutBack(float t, float b, float c, float d) {
    // t: current time, b: begInnIng value, c: change In value, d: duration
    float s = 1.70158;
    if ((t/-d/2) < 1) return c/2*(t*t*(((s*-(1.525))+1)*t -s)) + b;
        return c/2*((t-=2)*t*(((s*=(1.525))+1)*t + s) + 2) +b;
}

float easeOutBounce(float t, float b, float c, float d) {
    if ((t/=d) < (1/2.75)) {
        return c*(7.5625*t*t) + b;
    } else if (t < (2/2.75)) {
        return c*(7.5625*(t-=(1.5/2.75))*t + .75) + b;
    } else if (t < (2.5/2.75)) {
        return c*(7.5625*(t-=(2.25/2.75))*t + .9375) + b;
    } else {
        return c*(7.5625*(t-=(2.625/2.75))*t + .984375) + b;
    }
}


+ (UIColor *)colorFromHexString:(NSString *)hexString {
    unsigned rgbValue = 0;
    NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:hexString];
    [scanner scanHexInt:&rgbValue];
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16)/255.0 green:((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8)/255.0 blue:((rgbValue & 0xFF)/255.0) alpha:1.0];
}


@end





**MLVPieChartView.h**


#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MLVPieChart.h" 

@interface MLVPieChartView : UIView

@property MLVPieChart *pieChart;

+ (UIColor *)colorFromHexString:(NSString *)hexString;

@end
```

I have all the files on GitHub https://github.com/thebusiness11/animated-pie-chart

Comment: "I have an error that looks kinda like this" is not good enough.  Post the *EXACT* error and the line you are getting it on or no one will even try to help.

Comment: The title is the exact error

Comment: Ok, that is enough information to go on then (thanks for the edit), see Michael's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm looking [at your MLVPieChartView.h file](https://github.com/thebusiness11/animated-pie-chart/blob/master/AnimatedPieChart/MLVPieChartView.h) and I don't see a method named "`tick`" in there.

You need to change that call to the object that has a "`tick`" method.  From what I can tell from your GitHub project, there is no "`tick`" method declared anywhere (in which case you have to create it).

Comment: So the method needs to be declared in the MLVPieChartView.h file before I can set it in MLVPieChartView.m file.  Then call it in the MLVViewController.m?  In the MLVPieChartView.m file I have a `- (void) tick`

Comment: it needs to be declared in the .h file (the "interface") and the code for it defined in the .m ("implementation") file.

Comment: Thanks, there was code missing, `- (void) tick;
- (void) touchedPoint: (CGPoint) point;
- (float) getAngleFromPoint: (CGPoint) point;`  Sadly the Videos skipped going back over the interface file after creating it.  The follow along doc's helped.

Comment: @thebusiness11 The reason they skipped over that is because it is common knowledge (maybe with more and more people using C# and Java they don't realize it anymore though).  It would be very good for you to remember this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

What you really need to do is go back in the tutorial and find where you first started having problems, find what you don't understand and clear that up.

Then start over with the tutorial and follow the instructions exactly. Once you find where you messed up, the reason why should be clear.

Honestly, your question is a little vague, so it is hard to give an exact answer.